# Which YugabyteDB node am I connected to?

Tags: high-availability, yugabytedb

When using hosts list or JDBC smart driver, we can be connected to any database node in the cluster, or part of it. How can I know know which one I am currently connected to? With its availability zone, region, and cloud provider information?

Answer (score 3):

YugabyteDB `yb_servers()` exposes all nodes, with their placement, and PostgreSQL `inet_server_port()` exposes the server endpoint you are connected to, so joining both:

```
with yb_servers as (
       select host,port,cloud,region,zone from yb_servers()
   ), my_connection as (
      select host(inet_server_addr()) host, inet_server_port() port
      ,'<<- you are here' as inet_server)
 select * from yb_servers natural left join my_connection;
```

gives the following:

```
yugabyte=# with yb_servers as (
yugabyte(#       select host,port,cloud,region,zone from yb_servers()
yugabyte(#   ), my_connection as (
yugabyte(#      select host(inet_server_addr()) host, inet_server_port() port,'<<- you are here' as inet_server)
yugabyte-# select * from yb_servers natural left join my_connection;

      host      | port | cloud |   region   |    zone     |   inet_server
----------------+------+-------+------------+-------------+------------------
 172.129.25.209 | 5433 | aws   | eu-west-1  | eu-west-1a  | <<- you are here
 172.125.42.26  | 5433 | aws   | ap-south-1 | ap-south-1b |
 172.121.27.101 | 5433 | aws   | us-east-2  | us-east-2a  |

(3 rows)
```